# Make datatable columns resize on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I want to be able to resize all the columns to their content.

I'm using this code

```js
button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
    $("#table_id").DataTable().columns.adjust().draw();
});
```

But it doesn't do anything.

Here is my datatable initialization :

```js
// DataTable
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
    colReorder: true,
    scrollX: false,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "aLengthMenu": [
        [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 500, -1],
        [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 500, "All"]
    ],
    deferRender: false,
    'dom': 'ZBfrltip',
    buttons: ['copy', 'csv',
        {
            extend: 'colvis',
            prefixButtons: ['colvisRestore']
        }
    ],

    columnDefs: [{
        targets: '_all',
        visible: true
    }, {
        width: 200,
        targets: '_all'
    }],
});
```

The problem could come from the css but event when removing :

```css
table-layout:fixed;
width:100%;
```

Nothing changes

Comment: What if you preserve the reference `table` and use the same on button click handler `table.DataTable().columns.adjust().draw()` ?

Comment: I tried it too but the result is the same. I don't understand what is blocking the resizing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `autoWidth: true` along with `columns.adjust()` API method to adjust column width after you done adding data to the table.

Comment: I tried to use autoWidth : true but the columns are still not fitting the content.   
I tried to delete the initial column size definition to no vail

Comment: Did you tried DataTable().destroy() and then reinitialize datatable with autoWidth: true

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you to solve your problem.

1. remove `autowidth:false` from your datatable code.
2. remove `table-layout:fixed;` `width:100%;` this too.